# AspectJ - Pointcut for all classes in a package except one

Tags: java, class, spring-boot, package, aspectj

I am currently using the following pointcut on a method that logs calls to every service method in my app :

```
@Before("execution(* com.mdenis.someAppName..service..*(..))")
```

The method in question uses an Apache logger and works perfectly.  I now want these logging statements to be written to the database as well (through a LogEntryService class).  The issue is that this is essentially creating a StackOverflow error since the method that logs everything in the service package is calling a method inside that same package.

Is there a way to change my pointcut to exclude a certain class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up combining a class pointcut with an annotation pointcut like such :

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.service.processes.communication.CommunicationProcess.*(..))")
private void communicationMethods() {}

@Pointcut("execution(@com.lib.annotation.Loggable * *.*(..))")
private void loggableMethods() {}

@Before("communicationMethods() && loggableMethods()")
public void logMethodCallWithParameters(JoinPoint joinPoint)
{
    if (joinPoint.getArgs().length == 0)
    {
        logEntryService.logDebug(LogEntrySource.SERVICE, LogEntryType.MESSAGING, "Method " + joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getCanonicalName() 
            + "." + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + " called with no argument", logger);
    }
    else
    {
        logEntryService.logDebug(LogEntrySource.SERVICE, LogEntryType.MESSAGING, "Method " + joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getCanonicalName() 
            + "." + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + " called with argument(s) " + getArgumentString(joinPoint.getArgs()), logger);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```java
@Before(
  "execution(* com.mdenis.someAppName..service..*(..)) && " + 
  "!within(*..LogEntryService)"
)
```